# number of repetition of elements for each row increasing sequentially in excel

Tags: excel, function

I have the following table in excel.

```
 A   |  B |
-----|----|
Jack |Jack|       
Alice|Jack|    
Alice|Jack|    
Alice|Ben |    
Jack |Paul|
```

I need to found the rank of each value in A and B column in every single rows. I should mention that I do not need the total "count" for all the pair of "Alice" and "Jack". In fact, For example, I need just the number of repetition of "Alice" and "Jack" for each row increasing sequentially as below.

```
 A   |  B |Rank|   
-----|----|----|
Jack |Jack|  1 |   
Alice|Jack|  1 |
Alice|Jack|  2 |
Alice|Ben |  1 |
Alice|Jack|  3 |
```

Could you please tell me how should I write a function for that in Microsoft excel? Thanks in advance

Comment: What if it were the same name but different order?  What if `Jack` was in Column A and `Alice` in Column B would that start the count over or would it be `4`?

Comment: @ScottCraner: Thanks for your reply. The order is important and it should be start form small numbers to big numbers.
No, it should be just one way. (Only A-> B ----> Alice -> Jack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple COUNTIFS() with a dynamic range will do what you want:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)
```

The important part here is what is and what is not an absolute reference.

[image]